# Windows 10 Fall Creator Update and Virtual Box / Homestead freezes PC

Tags: virtualbox, windows-10-v1703

Any hints on where else too look pls? I am searching for this still but have not found anything that has helped. Thank you

---

I just updated Win 10 to Fall Creator's Update. My Virtualbox environment stopped working and would require the PC to be cold booted.

I just updated Virtualbox + extension pack and Homestead/Vagrant to the latest versions to try and fix this issue, but the result is the same. It has all been working up until this point for some 2 years now.

My network settings are:

```
Adapter 1: NAT
Adapter 2: Bridged Adapter
           Killer Ethernet Controller
           PCnet-FAST III (Am79C973)
           Allow All
           Cable Connected -> yes
```

Whether I start my homestead-7 box from Virtualbox of from a bash window, the result is the same. PC freezes and requires a cold boot.

My VBoxSVC.log file contains:

```
VirtualBox COM Server 5.2.0 r118431 win.amd64 (Oct 18 2017 06:24:56) release log
00:00:00.000000 main     Log opened 2017-11-21T06:44:33.784520500Z
00:00:00.000000 main     Build Type: release
00:00:00.000000 main     OS Product: Windows 10
00:00:00.000000 main     OS Release: 10.0.16299
00:00:00.000000 main     OS Service Pack: 
00:00:00.015627 main     DMI Product Name: Default string
00:00:00.015627 main     DMI Product Version: Default string
00:00:00.015627 main     Host RAM: 16221MB (15.8GB) total, 11734MB (11.4GB) available
00:00:00.015627 main     Executable: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxSVC.exe
00:00:00.015627 main     Process ID: 6164
00:00:00.015627 main     Package type: WINDOWS_64BITS_GENERIC
00:00:00.015627          VirtualBox: object creation starts
00:00:00.015627          Home directory: 'C:\Users\PAPA\.VirtualBox'
00:00:00.015627          Installed Drivers:
00:00:00.015627            C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\VBoxNetLwf.sys (Version: 5.2.0.18431)
00:00:00.015627            C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\VBoxUSBMon.sys (Version: 5.2.0.18431)
00:00:00.015627            C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\VBoxDrv.sys (Version: 5.2.0.18431)
00:00:00.015627            C:\WINDOWS\System32\drivers\VBoxNetAdp6.sys (Version: 5.2.0.18431)
00:00:00.015627          Loading settings file "C:\Users\PAPA\.VirtualBox\VirtualBox.xml" with version "1.14-windows"
00:00:00.184485          netIfIsWireless: CreateFile on '\\.\{21AD0D25-56F5-4F8A-8CB4-C922101B864A}' failed with rcWin=2 (0x2) - ignoring
00:00:00.184485          HostDnsMonitor: old information
00:00:00.184485            no server entries
00:00:00.184485            no domain set
00:00:00.184485            no search string entries
00:00:00.184485          HostDnsMonitor: new information
00:00:00.184485            server 1: 10.0.0.1
00:00:00.184485            domain: NHOME
00:00:00.184485            no search string entries
00:00:00.184485          HostDnsMonitorProxy::notify
00:00:00.231360          VD: VDInit finished with VINF_SUCCESS
00:00:00.231360          Loading settings file "F:\!! - VB VMs\Ansible Wordpress\Ansible Wordpress.vbox" with version "1.15-windows"
00:00:00.231360          Loading settings file "F:\!! - VB VMs\Ansible Wordpress Backup\Ansible Wordpress Backup.vbox" with version "1.15-windows"
00:00:00.231360          Loading settings file "F:\!! - VB VMs\Ansible Wordpress Target Test - MAIN\Ansible Wordpress Target Test - MAIN.vbox" with version "1.15-windows"
00:00:00.246985          Loading settings file "F:\!! - VB VMs\Ansible Wordpress Target Test - MAIN Clone\Ansible Wordpress Target Test - MAIN Clone.vbox" with version "1.15-windows"
00:00:00.247220          Loading settings file "F:\!! - VB VMs\FreePBX\FreePBX.vbox" with version "1.15-windows"
00:00:00.247729          Loading settings file "F:\!! - VB VMs\homestead-7\homestead-7.vbox" with version "1.15-windows"
00:00:00.257721          VirtualBox: object created
```

When I close Virtualbox this is added to the log:

```
00:00:00.391990          netIfIsWireless: CreateFile on '\\.\{21AD0D25-56F5-4F8A-8CB4-C922101B864A}' failed with rcWin=2 (0x2) - ignoring
00:00:03.161576          Saving settings file "C:\Users\PAPA\.VirtualBox\VirtualBox.xml" with version "1.14-windows"
00:00:03.177207          Saving settings file "C:\Users\PAPA\.VirtualBox\VirtualBox.xml" with version "1.14-windows"
00:00:08.700473 main     VirtualBox: object deletion starts
00:00:08.700473 main     ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_OBJECT_IN_USE (0x80bb000c) aIID={4afe423b-43e0-e9d0-82e8-ceb307940dda} aComponent={MediumWrap} aText={Medium 'F:\!! - VB VMs\Ansible Wordpress\Ansible Wordpress.vdi' cannot be closed because it is still attached to 1 virtual machines}, preserve=false aResultDetail=0
00:00:08.700473 main     ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_OBJECT_IN_USE (0x80bb000c) aIID={4afe423b-43e0-e9d0-82e8-ceb307940dda} aComponent={MediumWrap} aText={Medium 'F:\!! - VB VMs\Ansible Wordpress Backup\Ansible Wordpress Backup.vdi' cannot be closed because it is still attached to 1 virtual machines}, preserve=false aResultDetail=0
00:00:08.700473 main     ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_OBJECT_IN_USE (0x80bb000c) aIID={4afe423b-43e0-e9d0-82e8-ceb307940dda} aComponent={MediumWrap} aText={Medium 'F:\!! - VB VMs\Ansible Wordpress Target Test - MAIN\Ansible Wordpress Target Test Clone.vdi' cannot be closed because it is still attached to 1 virtual machines}, preserve=false aResultDetail=0
00:00:08.700473 main     ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_OBJECT_IN_USE (0x80bb000c) aIID={4afe423b-43e0-e9d0-82e8-ceb307940dda} aComponent={MediumWrap} aText={Medium 'F:\!! - VB VMs\Ansible Wordpress Target Test - MAIN Clone\Ansible Wordpress Target Test - MAIN Clone-disk1.vdi' cannot be closed because it is still attached to 1 virtual machines}, preserve=false aResultDetail=0
00:00:08.700473 main     ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_OBJECT_IN_USE (0x80bb000c) aIID={4afe423b-43e0-e9d0-82e8-ceb307940dda} aComponent={MediumWrap} aText={Medium 'F:\!! - VB VMs\FreePBX\FreePBX-disk1_1.vmdk' cannot be closed because it is still attached to 1 virtual machines}, preserve=false aResultDetail=0
00:00:08.700473 main     ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_OBJECT_IN_USE (0x80bb000c) aIID={4afe423b-43e0-e9d0-82e8-ceb307940dda} aComponent={MediumWrap} aText={Medium 'F:\!! - VB VMs\homestead-7\box-disk1.vmdk' cannot be closed because it is still attached to 1 virtual machines}, preserve=false aResultDetail=0
00:00:08.700473 Watcher  ERROR [COM]: aRC=E_ACCESSDENIED (0x80070005) aIID={9570b9d5-f1a1-448a-10c5-e12f5285adad} aComponent={VirtualBoxWrap} aText={The object is not ready}, preserve=false aResultDetail=0
00:00:08.700473 main     VirtualBox: object deleted
```

I do not understand what the `VBOX_E_OBJECT_IN_USE` errors are as the log shown above is generated by simply opening then closing Virtualbox (without starting a box).

Any ideas / help is really appreciated.

Comment: Is this problem only for WinV1709? Did you try to install updated VirtualBox without extension pack? Remove all VMs & clones and try with a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so some days later and more hair loss, here is what I found:

The freezing issue was to `HYPER-V` being on in `Windows 10`. I assume this happened due to the Fall Creator Update.

Open the start menu and type:

```
windows features
```

Then un-tick `HYPER-V`. This will require a reboot. This stopped the PC freezing and requiring a cold boot.

In my case I had updated `Virtualbox`, `Vagrant`, so my next issue was:

```
ssh auth method private key timeout
```

during the VM boot. To solve this I did:

```
vagrant destroy
vagrant up
```

You will need to re-run migrations and seeds to restore your data.